# CountUp timer for custom post

Tags: custom-post-type-archives

I have count up timer for my custom post. Each post is with different date to count up from , but the javascript currently is taking one date and all posts are counting up from same date. Here is link to the page - [link](http://izrabotka-sait.com/spasime/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8/)

I found the javascript example in codepen so i dont know how good is it . And i know not much about javascript.
here is my code so far:

```
<?php
$name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'animal-name', true ); 
$name2 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'animal-respond', true );
$vid = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'animal-type', true );
$breed = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'izdirvase-poroda', true );
$sex = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'izdirvase-sex', true );
$oblast = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'oblast', true );
$color = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'izdirvase-coloring', true );
$location = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'izdirvase-location', true );
$owner_name = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'izdirvase-owner', true );
$owner_phone = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'izdirvase-owner-phone', true );
$owner_fb = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'izdirvase-owner-fb', true );
$owner_tw = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'izdirvase-owner-tw', true );
$price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'izdirvase-price', true );
$lost_date_start = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'lost-start', true );
$current_date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s');

if ($lost_date_start != ''): $post_date_start = $lost_date_start;
else: $post_date_start = get_the_date("m/d/Y h:i:s"); 
endif;

if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'stop-timer', true) != 'yes'):
$count_date_end = date('12/31/2020 12:00:00');
endif;
?>
<div class="vc_row vc_row-fluid row vc_row-o-equal-height vc_row-flex lost-animal-wrapp">
    <div class="content-lost-animal wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-md-9">
        <div class="animal-gallery col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <?php the_content(); ?>    
        </div>
        <div class="animal-full-description col-md-8">
            <div class="animal-description">
            <?php the_title( '<h3 class="lost-animal-title">', '</h3>' ); ?>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'stop-timer', true) != 'yes' && $count_date_end < $current_date ) : ?>
            <div class="notfound">Не беше намерено <i class="icon-frown"></i> </div>
            <?php elseif(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'stop-timer', true) != 'yes'): ?>
            <div class="lost-since">
                <center>
                     <ul class="countdown">
                        <li>
                            <p class="days_ref">дни</p>
                            <span class="days"></span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="hours_ref">часа</p>
                            <span class="hours"></span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="minutes_ref">минути</p>    
                            <span class="minutes"></span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p class="seconds_ref">секунди</p>
                            <span class="seconds"></span>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                </center>            
            </div>
            <?php else: ?>
            <div class="found">Намерено е <i class="icon-smile"></i></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lost-animal-info wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-md-3">
        <div class="vc_column-inner">
        <div class="info-top">
    <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'izdirvase-reward', true) == 'yes'): ?>
        <?php if ($price !=''): ?>
            <div class="reward price"><?php echo $price; ?> <span class="currency">лв.</span></div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <div class="reward">Награда</div>
        <?php endif; ?>    
    <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="region"><?php echo $oblast; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="lost-animal-info">
            <p>Отличителни белези</p>
            <span class="la-text">Име <?php echo $name; ?></span>
            <span class="la-text">Отговаря на <?php echo $name2; ?></span>
            <span class="la-text">Вид <?php echo $vid; ?></span>
            <?php if($breed !=''): ?>
            <span class="la-text">Порода <?php echo $breed; ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <span class="la-text">Пол <?php echo $sex; ?></span>
            <span class="la-text">Цвят <?php echo $color; ?></span>
            <p>Изгубено в</p>
            <span class="la-text"><?php echo $location; ?></span>
            <p>Информация за собственика</p>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <span class="la-owner"><?php echo $owner_name; ?></span>
            <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'izdirvase-owner-viber', true) == 'yes'): ?>
            <span class="la-owner"><a href="tel:<?php echo $owner_phone; ?>"><i class="icon-whatsapp"></i><?php echo $owner_phone; ?></a></span>
            <?php else: ?>
            <span class="la-owner"><a href="tel:<?php echo $owner_phone; ?>"><?php echo $owner_phone; ?></a></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <span class="la-owner social fb"><a href="<?php echo $owner_fb; ?>" target="_blank"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a></span>
            <span class="la-owner social tw"><a href="<?php echo $owner_tw; ?>" target="_blank"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.downCount = function (options, callback) {
        var settings = $.extend({
                date: null,
                offset: null
            }, options);

        // Save container
        var container = this;

        /**
         * Change client's local date to match offset timezone
         * @return {Object} Fixed Date object.
         */
        var currentDate = function () {
            // get client's current date
            var date = new Date();

            // turn date to utc
            var utc = date.getTime() + (date.getTimezoneOffset());

            // set new Date object
            var new_date = new Date(utc + (3600000*settings.offset))

            return new_date;
        };

        /**
         * Main downCount function that calculates everything
         */
var original_date = new Date('<?php echo $post_date_start; ?>');
var target_date = new Date('<?php echo $count_date_end; ?>');

function countdown () {
        var current_date = currentDate(); // get fixed current date

        // difference of dates
        var difference = current_date - original_date;

        if (current_date >= target_date) {
            // stop timer
            clearInterval(interval);

            if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') callback();

            return;
        }

        // basic math variables
        var _second = 1000,
            _minute = _second * 60,
            _hour = _minute * 60,
            _day = _hour * 24;

        // calculate dates
        var days = Math.floor(difference / _day),
            hours = Math.floor((difference % _day) / _hour),
            minutes = Math.floor((difference % _hour) / _minute),
            seconds = Math.floor((difference % _minute) / _second);

            // fix dates so that it will show two digets
            days = (String(days).length >= 2) ? days : '0' + days;
            hours = (String(hours).length >= 2) ? hours : '0' + hours;
            minutes = (String(minutes).length >= 2) ? minutes : '0' + minutes;
            seconds = (String(seconds).length >= 2) ? seconds : '0' + seconds;

            // based on the date change the refrence wording
            var ref_days = (days === 1) ? 'ден' : 'дни',
                ref_hours = (hours === 1) ? 'час' : 'часа',
                ref_minutes = (minutes === 1) ? 'минута' : 'минути',
                ref_seconds = (seconds === 1) ? 'секунда' : 'секунди';

            // set to DOM
            container.find('.days').text(days);
            container.find('.hours').text(hours);
            container.find('.minutes').text(minutes);
            container.find('.seconds').text(seconds);

            container.find('.days_ref').text(ref_days);
            container.find('.hours_ref').text(ref_hours);
            container.find('.minutes_ref').text(ref_minutes);
            container.find('.seconds_ref').text(ref_seconds);
        };

        // start
        var interval = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
    };





$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.countdown').downCount();
});    
</script>
```

Comment: on the page of the link, the function of the 2nd element erase the definition of `downCount`. the first step to do is to put all JavaScript code in a separate file. And then you can put the start day in a attribute `data` for each counters and read it at the start of the function `countdown`.

Comment: Hello thanks for the hints - i did the following - Moved the script in file called lost-counttime.js , then i add data-countup attribute in countdown class
and this script 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("[data-countup]").each(function() {
var original_date = new Date('<?php echo $post_date_start; ?>');
var target_date = new Date('<?php echo $count_date_end; ?>');
});
});
</script>
but returns NaN so i guess i did something wrong again.

Comment: the data attribut is set in PHP in the HTML result and then you read it with JavaScript with `$(...).data("countup")`